# Tkinter in fullscreen mode makes Text widget not work

Tags: python, tkinter

When using Tkinter as a regular window, the text widget works as intended and can be typed in.

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

T = Text(root, height=2, width=30)
T.pack()
T.insert(END, "Just a text Widget\nin two lines\n")
mainloop()
```

However if we make this application fullscreen:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
T = Text(root, height=2, width=30)
T.pack()
T.insert(END, "Just a text Widget\nin two lines\n")
mainloop()
```

And try to type in the textbox, it won't work and the keys will instead appear in the terminal. Why is this and is there a solutoin?

Comment: I've tried your code and I have not had any problems.

Comment: @eyllanesc it may depends on system. What do you use - Windows/Linux/Mac ?

Comment: @furas linux lovers :P

Comment: Thanks guys, my examples weren't quite right for my question. I've discovered that my issue was using root.overrideredirect(1) root.geometry("...") instead of root.attributres("-fullscreen", True). I was confused because I had an error in my example when I was debugging.

Answer (score 0):

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

root = tk.Tk()

root.overrideredirect(True)

root.overrideredirect(False)

root.attributes('-fullscreen',True)

canvas= Canvas(root)

canvas.create_text(300, 50,text="This is a window", fill="black", font=('Helvetica 15 bold'))

canvas.pack()
```

This seems to be working with me

Comment: How about checking the markdown guide.  This way your answer is more clear... :)